# Is the django documentation wrong here?

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions

It seems to mention aggregate functions but then use annotations as an example, am I going crazy or is there something I'm missing here? I'm having a hell of time trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate functions like [**`Count`** [Djanog-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count), [**`Sum`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Sum), etc. both in an [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) and [**`.aggregate(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) function call.

But the two are *not* the same. An `.aggregate(..)` means that we calculate the `COUNT(*)`, `SUM(*)`, etc. over the entire queryset. `.aggregate(..)` will make an *eager* database call, and return a dictionary that contains the keys, that map to the value that is obtained from the `COUNT(*)`, etc.

The `.annotate(..)` on the other hand is used to make aggregates *per* object. So it will translate this to a query with a `GROUP BY` part. It will add extra attributes to the model objects (or other objects) that arise from the queryset. An `.annotate(..)` produces a new queryset, it will thus *lazily* query the database.

**Example**: Say we have the following model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then we can count the number of `Book`s for all author's with a name that starts with `'Alice'` with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Author.objects.filter(name__startswith='Alice').aggregate(books=Count('book'))
```

Here we thus will retrieve a dictionary, like `{'books': 1425}`, that contains the total number of books written by an `Author` who's name starts with `'Alice'`. The query query will look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(book.id) AS books
FROM author
LEFT OUTER JOIN book ON book.author_id = author.id
WHERE author.name LIKE 'Alice%'
```

So we here count all the books, and obtain one result.

We can however use `.annotate(..)` as well:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Author.objects.filter(name__startswith='Alice').annotate(books=Count('book'))
```

This is a queryset that will, if evaluated, result in a collection of `Author`s. Each `Author` that arises from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.book` that contains the number of books *that* author has written.

Here the query will thus look like:

```
SELECT author.*, COUNT(book.id) AS books
FROM author
LEFT OUTER JOIN book ON book.author_id = author.id
WHERE author.name LIKE 'Alice%'
GROUP BY author.id
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I was going nuts staring at docs for hours.